# Сортировка в ListView

Tags: android, сортировка, java

Можно ли как-то сортировать список `ListView`?

Например, расположить элементы в алфавитном порядке?

Answer (score 2):

Какойто неправильный вопрос, `view` - это всего лишь тип представления данных и ему по сути все равно, что и как показывать.

Сортировать данные ты можешь использовать статический метод `Collections.sort();` и расширить обьект `public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject>` и переопределив метод `compareTo`.

Comment: или передавая компаратор в Collections.sort() вторым параметром